# I hear a weird noise from my pc

Tags: fan, noise

I hear a weird noise coming from my PC. It sounds like a fan is touching a cable but I can't see where, and the sound is intermittent. I don’t know what is causing this sound, can someone help me or tell me what is causing this noise?
https://youtu.be/hi--GISk_N0

Comment: First guess: fan bearing is dry. Open it up, add some oil. If that doesn't help, the bearing might be already be damaged.

Comment: Thanks.I will try this and I will tell you how will go.